# Interrupting a long running javax.ejb.TimerService Job

Tags: jakarta-ee

I'm using the Java EE 6 TimerService to execute a long running task (about 30min). This task could easily be interrupted because its business logic is capable of beeing canceled about every 5 seconds.

Now the question is how I can get the event of undeploying the application within the executed method so I'm able to cancel execution in case of re- and undeployment in the Java EE container.

Example:

```
@Singleton
public class AnyClass {

    @Schedule(hour = "9", minute="17")
    public void service() {
        for(i = 1000; i < 1000; i++) {
            doSomethingForAbout5Seconds();
            // here I want to cancel the execution in 
            // case of undeployment of the apllication
        }
    }
}
```